# Grails - get the properties which are modified by databinding

Tags: grails, data-binding

```
def action(Domain domainInstance){

}
```

If we want to save some events based on the changes in the `domainInstance` properties, how to get, which properties are updated in the databinding of grails while submitting the form, how to get the old values in-case of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getDirtyPropertyNames`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getDirtyPropertyNames.html) to get the properties that were modified by the binding. One each such property you could use [`getPersistentValue`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getPersistentValue.html) to get the actual/persisted value before the binding:

Refer [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23600966/2051952) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18797345/2051952) similar answers for details.